# laravel 5 methods only() or except() issues

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a problem in laravel in using the `only()` and `except` methods.

Official documentation:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-only
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-except

Using:

- `$data = Model::whereId($id)->first();`
  or
- `$data = Model::whereId($id)->get()->except('updated_at', 'deleted_at');`

I get:

```
{"id":21,"name":"new one","description":"desc","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-03-08 16:23:01","updated_at":"2017-03-08 16:23:01"}
```

with:

```
$data = Model::whereId($id)->get()->only('id', 'name', 'description', 'created_at');
```

I get an empty result.

I am pretty sure I'm not calling the method in the right way.
I have also tried calling it after getting the result from DB, like `$data->only('...')` or `$data->except('...')` without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange enough, I managed to do it by creating a new variable which will hold a `collect()` of the result (which is model instance)

So this worked:

```
    $data = Model::whereId($id)->first();
    $return = collect($data)->except('updated_at', 'deleted_at');

    return Response::json($return);
```

Somehow it makes sense as it's not a model related method, but parsing collection object one.

Comment: But what's the point on geting the timestamps first (first line) and then excepting them. I know that will works but it's double works. For instance, I have a Model with a column that it's very heavy, and I can't retrieve it with eloquent (each registry of that column it's like 1MB, it's a geometry shape), so this won't work because I will have to retrieve it anyway. Instead, I had to use `select` picking the columns that I needed it excepting the heavy one (the shape)